# Multiple UIPickerView in ScrollView not Hiding

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I have a Hidden multiple UIPickerView working fine in a static app. However when I add it to an app with a scroll view it no longer hides when you press away from the picker.

UIPickerView:

```
picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,400,160)];
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:picker];


}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    picker.hidden = YES;
}
```

Is there anything I need to add because it is now in a scrollview?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by adding this piece of code to after viewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: tapRec];
}

-(void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRec
{
    [[self view] endEditing: YES];
    // Hide picker
    [picker resignFirstResponder];
    picker.hidden = YES;

}
```